# Folder has gone missing on webserver

Tags: ftp

I was trying to rename a folder on my Linux webserver. I added a double slash infront of older name e.g //foldername. Now the ftp showed this message

> Renaming '/public_html/cache/test' to '/test'
>   Command:   RNFR test
>   Response:  350 RNFR accepted - file exists, ready for destination
>   Command:   RNTO /test

Comment: I think you don't use the command correct, you don't have to put `/` in front of the name you want to put, example :
`mv /public_html/cache/test test`
It went to your root folder because `mv` is both `rename` and `move` command, and with the slash it is accepted as move command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the files inside the ROOT directory of your server.

Example:

```
root@dev7:/# cd /
root@dev7:/# ls
bin   etc         lib         mnt   root     srv  usr
boot  home        lost+found  opt   sbin     sys  var
dev   initrd.img  media       proc  selinux  tmp  vmlinuz
root@dev7:/# cd //
root@dev7://# ls
bin   etc         lib         mnt   root     srv  usr
boot  home        lost+found  opt   sbin     sys  var
dev   initrd.img  media       proc  selinux  tmp  vmlinuz
root@dev7://
```

As you know, `./` means `current directory` and `../` means `parent directory` but `/` and `//` and even `//(...)` all go to the ROOT. (Why it displays two `//` in `root@dev7://#` beats me.)

My guess is that you now have another folder in your root directory, `/test` and you should check that.

Comment: Thanks ... it really went it to the root... Now a little more help... I tried this when finding .... rnfr /app rnto app .... what does this command do?

Comment: @backTangent - I'd stick with the "move" command: `mv /path/to/folder /path/to/newfolder` You really shouldn't be doing the `rnfr rnto` commands, those are FTP commands. (Your FTP server will pick those up and actually execute the `mv` command). For "renaming" files, you just `cd` into the directory you want, and issue `mv oldfile.txt newfile.txt` which actually does `cp oldfile.txt newfile.txt;rm oldfile.txt` but saves a copy in `/target/` (not accessible by default). Don't worry about any of that.